# Read environment tags from other dockers in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to know if it can be done and if so, how to do it, to be able to read the environment tags.

I leave an example of what I have seen and I am not able to find information with which to understand how it does it (docker compose):

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: budry/jwilder-nginx-proxy-arm:0.6.0
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - confd:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhostd:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
    labels:
      - com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy

  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:stable
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - confd:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhostd:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html

  nginx:
    image: tobi312/php:7.4-fpm-nginx-alpine-arm
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "80"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=example.host.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=example.host.com
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=example@mail.com
volumes:
  certs:
  html:
  vhostd:
  confd:
```

In this example you can see that the dockers `nginx-proxy` and `letsencrypt` are able to read the tags `VIRTUAL_HOST`, `LETSENCRYPT_HOST` and `LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL`. My question is, how do they do that and how can I do it? I would like to use this in a dockerFile, but I expect anything

This doubt appears because of what is explained [here (nginx-proxy)](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy)

Thanks in advance for any help

##### UPDATE:

I found [this code](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion/blob/master/app/letsencrypt_service_data.tmpl) among the letsencrypt files and something similar among the nginx files (but longer). I think what I'm looking for is something like that, but I don't know or understand what it does exactly

```
LETSENCRYPT_CONTAINERS=({{ range $host, $containers := groupBy $ "Env.LETSENCRYPT_HOST" }}{{ range $container := $containers }} '{{ printf "%.12s" $container.ID }}' {{ end }}{{ end }})

{{ range $hosts, $containers := groupBy $ "Env.LETSENCRYPT_HOST" }}

{{ range $container := $containers }}{{ $cid := printf "%.12s" $container.ID }}
LETSENCRYPT_{{ $cid }}_HOST=( {{ range $host := split $hosts "," }}'{{ $host }}' {{ end }})
LETSENCRYPT_{{ $cid }}_EMAIL="{{ $container.Env.LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL }}"
LETSENCRYPT_{{ $cid }}_TEST="{{ $container.Env.LETSENCRYPT_TEST }}"
{{ end }}

{{ end }}
```

(That it uses the variable `$containers` and that it contains `Env.LETSENCRYPT_HOST` gives me to understand that it is reading the `enviorement` declared in other containers)

Comment: In this example, those environment variables should only be set for the third container but not the first two.  Can you demonstrate through code that they're being set everywhere?

Comment: I actually use the project above (automatic nginx reverse proxy for docker containers). 1) this cannot work as is since the `nginx-proxy` container needs a mount to the docker controller socket. 2) if set up correctly, the container uses the socket to listen to docker container events (e.g. "a container is starting") and reads their configuration looking for well know env variables. It will use that to create a template configuration for a vhost, eventually ask for letsencrypt certs through the companion and reload the reverse proxy conf. More info: https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy

Comment: I think I have to thank you [@Zeitounator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9401096), but I don't know ... I haven't been able to understand how he does it.  Could you give an example?

Comment: The update you've posted is also mounting the docker socket. With that you can run the ps and inspect commands listed in my answer below. The cli we typically use is a thin interface to the [docker API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/) these apps may be using directly.

Answer (score 0):

You've left out a key detail in the example. The nginx-proxy includes a bind mount of the docker.sock file which gives direct access to the docker API and root on the host. With that API access, it's able to do the equivalent of:

```
docker ps -q # list all container id's
docker inspect ${id} # get each container config
```

Without that, a container should not be able to see the host or another container unless there's some kind of security vulnerability (and mounting the socket is a common vulnerability that will show up on many scanners).

You may achieve your desired result with yaml anchors and aliases, and extension fields may also be useful. But that's copying the same variable to multiple places so you don't repeat yourself, not viewing the settings of another container from inside the container.

```
version: '3'

# x- fields are extension fields, ignored by compose file parsers
# the & is an anchor, effectively defining a variable
x-shared-vars: &shared-vars
  VIRTUAL_HOST: "example.host.com"
  LETSENCRYPT_HOST: "example.host.com"
  LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: "example@mail.com"

services:
  nginx:
    image: "tobi312/php:7.4-fpm-nginx-alpine-arm"
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "80"
    environment:
      # the <<: merges the variable with other key/values
      # the * syntax is an alias, uses the variable
      <<: *shared-vars
      NGINX_SPECIFIC_VAR: "some value"

  other-service:
    image: some-image
    environment:
      # or use the alias without merging
      *shared-vars
```

Comment: 1)Update the code with what was missing.  2)I understand more or less what you mean, could you give a quick example?

Comment: @ICIM I added an example of the anchor/alias syntax

Comment: Maybe I'm dumber than I thought, but I can't figure out how to create a docker that can read those variables (from each of them). Are you declaring generic variables?  I don't even know which container to read and which one has the variable

Comment: @ICIM In my yaml anchor/alias example, you are just setting the same variables on multiple containers. It's not reading other containers. If you have the docker socket, you can run docker commands like I've listed above, but you can also run any docker command which is a security risk.

Comment: now I understand what you wanted to tell me.  The truth is that I like it, but it is not what I am looking for or I think it is not

Comment: @ICIM what you're probably looking for is some kind of advanced service discovery. That's going to be a database server. Docker doesn't have a metadata service exposed to containers, the most you get is DNS resolution which won't have the data you want.